# Displaying the Linux Apache directory format on Windows

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows

I've got a website hosted on Apache on Linux, and we need to migrate it to Apache on Windows.  Unfortunately, we have utility programs which parse the directory listing Apache provides to explore the filesystem.  The Windows directory listing is different, and break the programs.

Is there a way to get the same HTML generated for a directory listing on Windows, as is generated on Linux?

Comment: How is the directory listing on Windows different from the one on Linux?

Comment: I seem to faintly recall the IIS FTP function having a Unix style radio button option, but can't recollect that the web server function also has this. I don't think it's inconcievable as both the FTP and web server are included in the same IIS package. It might sit a bit more under the hood though.